# Convert MDE file to MDB

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-office, converters

how to convert MDE file to MDB?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2ryY.png)

I can't change design the form because design view is disable.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You may have a bit of luck with the [MDE forms/reports extractor v1.2](http://accesstools.narod.ru/) tool.

But no code.

Comment: Hi Gustav you for your help,but it's can't run,with dialog error ":Critical Error"

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. There are services for that.
http://www.everythingaccess.com/mdeconversion.asp

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible. MDE is compiled version, forms, reports and code cannot be edited.